# Docker java pass startup param to jar

Tags: java, docker

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8 
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/Demo.jar demo.jar   
RUN sh -c 'touch /demo.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /demo.jar" ]
```

And my question is how can i pass some startup param like in normal call .jar file. For example when i call:

> `java -jar demo.jar param1 param2`

Then i can get param1 in my app, so tell my how to perform my Dockerfile to pass param ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to pass the parameters param1 and param2, you can either pass them directly in your Dockfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /demo.jar param1 param2" ]
```

or if you want to set them from outside, you can use an environment variable, for instance:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /demo.jar $my_params" ]
```

and then run it with the `-e` option:

```
docker run -e my_params="param1 param2" ...
```

Comment: I want to run docker from script in bash where i put arg for example my call of script is:  ./script.sh hi. and in script i call : docker run -p 8080:8080 test -e my_param=$1. when i put into ENTRYPOINT $my_params, i dont get it in demo.jar

Comment: @djdecks93 Be careful, "docker run -p 8080:8080 test -e my_param=$1" contains two errors, use "docker run -e my_params=$1 -p 8080:8080 test" instead. The first is a typo (my_params vs my_param), but the other is more subtile: If you put the "-e" option after the container name, it will not be used.